# BouncyTree Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm currently in a run around issue. I'm looking to use BouncyCastle PGP for encryption of files. The situation is that I have public keys (basic asc) that are supplied that I need to use. I've been searching for the way to perform the encryption but everything is centered around utilization of key rings. I've found articles talking about using PgpPublicKeyRingBundle (C#) and just loading the ASC into that to create a keyring. Unfortunately this does not work. So my question is - how do I encrypt a file using BoundyTree when all I have is a key file (asc) and not a keyring. If someone could point out how in BouncyTree you create a keyring using a ASC file OR how to encrypt only using a ASC file would be greatly helpful.

Maybe I should make myself more clear. I have been trying to use BouncyTree to perform encryption on a file. It is more centered around using a key ring for performing operations. I'm not really clear on how to use BouncyTree when I only have a simple key fle - not a key ring file. I've read there are ways to prepare a key ring file and to get a simple key file for use as a key ring file. In the end I found the following works:

`factory     = new PgpObjectFactory(testPubKey); 
    temp        = factory.NextPgpObject() as PgpPublicKeyRing;
    pubKey      = temp.GetPublicKey();`

I found this out when I came across the PgpObjectFactory and that it takes a byte array. Getting a byte array was a bit confusing because I thought the underlying PGP functions would properly process the key file. I found this was not the case. What I had to do was the following to get a byte array that worked properly

```
private byte[] PrepKey(string KeyFile)
    {        
        string strPubKey    = File.ReadAllText(KeyFile);

        byte[] testPubKey;
            //    Base64.Decode(
            ////"-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" +
            ////"Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0" +
            ////"\r\n" +
            //    "mQENBFW5KbYBCADPl4qP61eKcls5q6tHrhAEimST4BSStlAQmGjhkANVJIFLAcCm" +
            //    "kOxFtGvtSH3EOycSc98hlh5+BlsliCtRNxHpZTzfHk9UZymb3SIAhGsAYrBVhTgc" +
            //    "AoGFDnNaCGCWSoAkLMwChPQc5vURCa3kzSfxmjTXAZOygj9rO0VdJMTrf9J7lJ6n" +
            //    "cC27/cmbMxqnOSa3pF2FyRr1q6H/Fux0nZgr24rkYs+TZetwhRv24HkI5Ad9Rdxi" +
            //    "QIBc/p3n9Zc8n4nTJHEfWUJq+k69K8MmO0byxQQ+PVXdpr9wH8DgavVZm/lVSPwN" +
            //    "YaEaR5AxzR2NC4ZEdVv3oGtYP/iLPzdkPb6VABEBAAG0AIkBHAQQAQIABgUCVbkp" +
            //    "tgAKCRCp8nOh8WrJThw8B/wO0B/TACRAVX1rGmMuQ1lqJSiw6EoPY20Tl3nXQ7Fv" +
            //    "aq9OQ6YN20/lPXepqHp5xUzZ0klcwd4FRb78idU5XaxWh3lGeLmcK1Kxwcq85Jnl" +
            //    "hrxq28r1rU045db+czjVvcAniBS1VogWSUFlDhGDxZk3mdG/8otwFV1CFUIT7NEB" +
            //    "Py3+gpwI6rp3tgJhk21OzBtBTW/m4l7UUdc1eb9kpJzymZ49YSTjYh6zDCyI397j" +
            //    "znnfsCICD6L5ZFxlfSJZthQjtOYavwlPdyJqgAiNdhnhKNPIxkNWM2tyBqUZqlso" +
            //    "aSE2qQyWw+JnDEl0HJLKwXPTvCqUZ282vcDL2Z1fScjO"
            ////"=f4/l\r\n" +
            ////"-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----"
            //    );


        var lines = (strPubKey.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)).ToList();
        for (int i = lines.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[i].Trim())) lines.RemoveAt(i);

        lines.RemoveRange(0, 2);
        lines.RemoveRange(lines.Count - 2, 2);
        testPubKey = Base64.Decode(string.Join(string.Empty, lines));

        return testPubKey;
    }
```

Now this simply removes lines from the originating file and excludes line feeds. As I said this works but I'm not really sure this is the correct way to load a key file for use by the PGP functions. What I would like to know is if this operation is correct or if there is a more correct/better way to do this (or am I doing something that is not necessary - but again it was the only way I could get the PGP functions to process the key file).

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it comes down performing a PGP encryption activity is not as straight forward as you would think. My concern was that I did not want to manage a key-ring. I just wanted to encrypt a file based on a typical public key definition. Using BouncyCastle seems to have the capability and you can review the specifics I have updated in the original description. The main issue deals with getting the raw key data based on the standard key file generated by key generators. My solution does strip the parts that can;t be used by BouncyCastle PGP processor and I tested on multiple keys to make sure. BUT I ran into an issue with a public key specifying DSA encryption. As it stands BouncyCastle does not support DSA - which was a bit frustrating but the comments indicated by people who know about this topic indicated that DSA is not considered a valid/good encryption, and BouncyCastle does not handle it because of this. If you go through the BouncyCastle code you see that when is set DSA for use in encryption assertions are thrown - stating DSA is not handled.

So with that said you can use a straight PGP key for encryption with OpenCastle if you prepare it properly but not all possible keys can be used.